# Problems wrapping jasper report exporter

Tags: java, generics, jasper-reports

I'm attempting to create a wrapper for the Jasper reports exporter.

Below I have a base class definition.

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.Exporter; 

abstract public class ExportBase<ExporterType extends Exporter< ExporterInput, ? extends ReportExportConfiguration,? extends ExporterConfiguration, ? extends ExporterOutput>>{
    protected ExporterType exporter;
    abstract protected void setExporter();
    ...
}
```

Then in a sub class I have something like this where I specialize the class for a specific jasper exporter type.

```
public class CsvExport extends ExportBase<JRCsvExporter>{
    protected void setExporter() { exporter = new JRCsvExporter();}
    ...
}
```

The problem is I get a compile error saying

`error: type argument JRCsvExporter is not within bounds of type-variable ExporterType`

but `JRCsvExporter` is descended from `net.sf.jasperreports.export.Exporter` via

```
public class JRCsvExporter extends JRAbstractCsvExporter<CsvReportConfiguration, CsvExporterConfiguration, JRCsvExporterContext>
```

Then

```
public abstract class JRAbstractCsvExporter<RC extends CsvReportConfiguration, C extends CsvExporterConfiguration, E extends JRExporterContext> extends JRAbstractExporter<RC, C, WriterExporterOutput, E> {
```

Then

```
public abstract class JRAbstractExporter<RC extends ReportExportConfiguration, C extends ExporterConfiguration, O extends ExporterOutput, E extends JRExporterContext> implements JRExporter<ExporterInput, RC, C, O> {
```

Then

```
public interface JRExporter<I extends ExporterInput, IC extends ReportExportConfiguration, C extends ExporterConfiguration, O extends ExporterOutput> extends Exporter<I, IC, C, O> {
```

And finally

```
public interface Exporter<I extends ExporterInput, IC extends ReportExportConfiguration, C extends ExporterConfiguration, O extends ExporterOutput> {
```

Given that it's a descendent I figured it would work to make it the basis for my type parameter constraint, seeing as it is shared between all the different exporter types and has all the methods I need. If there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do please let me know.

Comment: I tried the above ExportBase and CsvExport  with the only metod you included in code and I do not have compliation errors.

Comment: It seems it was my fault. I had an old version of the library still being included. I removed it and the code compiled correctly.

Comment: Great, if you feel this question can be useful for others, but your solution as a answer and accept it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mistakenly had an older version of the library in addition to the new one. Removing the old version resolved the issue.